# Flutter Scrolling widget inside a Scrolling widget

Tags: dart, flutter

Hello I am building this page https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/460823618805563392/526802427836366848/unknown.png

```
ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new RopSayac(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
              stackvideos(),
            ],
          );
        },
      )
```

This is my first listView and there is another listview in stack videos too.

```
  new CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 50.0,
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new VideoTile();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Video tile is ordinary component which returns an image and text

My full code

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import '../Theme.dart' as Theme;
    import '../Components/ropSayac.dart';
    import '../Components/Stackvideostile.dart';

    class Ropo extends StatelessWidget {
      Widget didvideomounted(bool asd) {
        if (asd == true) {
          return new Text("video");
        } else
          return new Container(
            width: 226.0,
            height: 226.0,
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: new Border.all(
                    width: 5.0, color: Theme.Colors.roportajheroborder)),
          );
      }

      Widget stackvideos() {
        return new Container(
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            color: Theme.Colors.tabbarbackground,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40.0, bottom: 10.0),
          width: 358.0,
          height: 343.0,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                // Üstteki bar
                width: 358.0,
                height: 46.0,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.Colors.stackvideostopbar,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8.0)),
                  boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
                    new BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      blurRadius: 3.0,
                      offset: new Offset(0.0, 7.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),

                child: Center(
                  child: new Text(
                    "BENCE Bİ’ ÖNCEKİLERE DE GÖZ AT",
                    style: Theme.TextStyles.stackvideotitle,
                  ),
                ),
              ), //üstteki bar bitti
              new CustomScrollView(
                slivers: <Widget>[
                  SliverFixedExtentList(
                    itemExtent: 50.0,
                    delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return new VideoTile();
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      List<String> lists = ["asdas","adadsa"];


      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          color: Theme.Colors.pagebackground,
          child: new Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0, top: 37.0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "assets/k.png",
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: 1,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new RopSayac(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                      stackvideos(),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              )

              //new Image.asset("name"),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

And This is the error log

Performing hot restart...
Restarted application in 2.163ms.
I/flutter ( 1664): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 1664): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter ( 1664): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.
I/flutter ( 1664): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a vertical
I/flutter ( 1664): viewport was given an unlimited amount of vertical space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter ( 1664): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter ( 1664): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter ( 1664): there will always be enough vertical space for the children. In this case, consider using a Column
I/flutter ( 1664): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter ( 1664): the height of the viewport to the sum of the heights of its children.
I/flutter ( 1664):
I/flutter ( 1664): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter ( 1664): #0      RenderViewport.performResize. (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1129:15)
I/flutter ( 1664): #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1182:6)
I/flutter ( 1664): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1619:9)
I/flutter ( 1664): #3      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #5      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #19     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
I/flutter ( 1664): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #23     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:258:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #25     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter ( 1664): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #27     RenderFlex.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:738:15)
I/flutter ( 1664): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #31     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #33     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:164:27)
I/flutter ( 1664): #34     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #35     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
I/flutter ( 1664): #36     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #37     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:405:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #38     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1645:12)
I/flutter ( 1664): #39     RenderShrinkWrappingViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1608:20)
I/flutter ( 1664): #40     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #41     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #43     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #45     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #47     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #49     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #51     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #53     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #55     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #57     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter ( 1664): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #59     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #60     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #61     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #62     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #63     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:104:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #64     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #65     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:404:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #66     RenderSliverFixedExtentBoxAdaptor.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_fixed_extent_list.dart:208:17)
I/flutter ( 1664): #67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1634:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #68     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:405:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #69     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1316:12)
I/flutter ( 1664): #70     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1234:20)
I/flutter ( 1664): #71     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1509:7)
I/flutter ( 1664): #72     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:768:18)
I/flutter ( 1664): #73     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:281:19)
I/flutter ( 1664): #74     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:677:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #75     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:219:5)
I/flutter ( 1664): #76     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter ( 1664): #77     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter ( 1664): #78     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter ( 1664): #79     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:13)
I/flutter ( 1664): #80     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:143:3)
I/flutter ( 1664):
I/flutter ( 1664): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter ( 1664):   RenderViewport#cbee0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664):   creator: Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#64e81] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter ( 1664):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#cbd61] ←
I/flutter ( 1664):   _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#a720b] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ←
I/flutter ( 1664):   NotificationListener ← ⋯
I/flutter ( 1664):   parentData:  (can use size)
I/flutter ( 1664):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=358.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
I/flutter ( 1664):   size: MISSING
I/flutter ( 1664):   axisDirection: down
I/flutter ( 1664):   crossAxisDirection: right
I/flutter ( 1664):   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#fcda8(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
I/flutter ( 1664):   ScrollableState, AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics -> ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#c3243,
I/flutter ( 1664):   ScrollDirection.idle)
I/flutter ( 1664):   anchor: 0.0
I/flutter ( 1664): This RenderObject had the following child:
I/flutter ( 1664):   RenderSliverFixedExtentList#ca02f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#cbee0 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#cbee0 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#4f553 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#d1753 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#b4cae relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#62acb relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#7332f relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#48bf2 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#4a9f4 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#15069 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#98b62 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#0943d NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#8d0dc relayoutBoundary=up16 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#9c2c8 relayoutBoundary=up15 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#362d5 relayoutBoundary=up14 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#fcd25 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderShrinkWrappingViewport#f1d5d relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#80ce2 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#915f2 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#34258 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#ff619 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#6b62a relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#34543 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#e9b84 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4d7e6 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderStack#59c67 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderDecoratedBox#6f453 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#3ecf2 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIndexedSemantics#54d44 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4d7e6 relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter ( 1664): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 461 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
E/flutter ( 1664): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(184)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 1664): Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
E/flutter ( 1664): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox:
E/flutter ( 1664):   RenderIndexedSemantics#54d44 NEEDS-PAINT
E/flutter ( 1664): Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set. A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
E/flutter ( 1664): #0      RenderBox.hitTest. (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1901:9)
E/flutter ( 1664): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1912:6)
E/flutter ( 1664): #2      _RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor&RenderSliver&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1475:22)
E/flutter ( 1664): #3      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:475:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #4      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1141:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #5      RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:572:43)
E/flutter ( 1664): #6      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #8      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #9      RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2777:37)
E/flutter ( 1664): #10     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #11     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #12     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #13     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:160:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #14     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #15     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #16     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #17     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #18     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #19     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #20     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #21     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:501:18)
E/flutter ( 1664): #22     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #24     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #25     _RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2256:17)
E/flutter ( 1664): #26     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:366:12)
E/flutter ( 1664): #27     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #28     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #29     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #30     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:113:19)
E/flutter ( 1664): #31     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1914:11)
E/flutter ( 1664): #32     RenderPhysicalModel.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/prox

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the `CustomScrollView` widget and change your layout :

Change this:

```
       ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 1,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                new RopSayac(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
                stackvideos(),
              ],
            );
          },
        )


  new CustomScrollView(
    slivers: <Widget>[
      SliverFixedExtentList(
        itemExtent: 50.0,
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return new VideoTile();
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

To this:

```
   CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: RopSayac(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width),
          ),
          SliverFixedExtentList(
            itemExtent: 50.0,
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
              (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new VideoTile();
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

Comment: I am writing as a new answer look down